# "onto" versus "on to"

Tags: grammar, differences, prepositions, orthography, spacing

Should the single word *onto* or the two words *on to* be used here?

> She held **onto** the cushion instead of holding **onto** the metal frame.
>   She was grabbing **onto** the seat cushion.
>   There's nothing saying what hand to use to hold **onto** any portion of the helicopter, and what part of the helicopter not to hold **onto** while getting in.

Comment: [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=held+on+to%2Cheld+onto%2C+stepped+on+to%2C+stepped+onto&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cheld%20on%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cheld%20onto%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstepped%20on%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstepped%20onto%3B%2Cc0) shows that "onto" is a relatively new contraction in English, and that its usage isn't completely stabilized yet.

Comment: 'After passing through Ipswich they continued on to Norwich'. (Definitely not 'onto') But 'He lifted the heavy box onto the table' sounds as if 'onto' would work.

Comment: @PeterShor It's certainly not a contraction. *On to* and *onto* are totally different.

Comment: @Sebasian: Before around 1800, everybody wrote *on to* and *onto* was not used. After 1800, some people started writing *onto* for ***some*** uses where they'd previously written *on to*. In 1822, an author actually felt compelled to defend his use of *onto* in [a footnote](https://books.google.com/books?id=66YUAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA40&dq=onto&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjAxaOMxaLVAhXGGD4KHSSbCuMQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=onto&f=false). That sounds like a contraction to me.

Comment: @WS2 In that example, "to" is short for "towards". When using "to" in that sense, you cannot replace the phrase with "onto". Otherwise, I believe *on to* and *onto* mean the same thing. As a funny aside, my browser wants to correct *on to* to *onto*.

Comment: @ArthurDent "they continued on towards Norwich" has a quite different meaning to "they continued on to Norwich". In the latter case the clear implication is that they reached Norwich.

Comment: @WS2 Now that you put it that way, you are correct.

Comment: @ArthurDent Indeed one can go "toward" somewhere, without any intention of going "to" the place.

Comment: @ArthurDent Respectfully, *on to* and *onto* aren't the same thing, and there is a huge difference between the two.

Comment: @SebastianPojman Yes I already admitted there is a difference. However, there are plenty of circumstances where they *are* the same thing. Calling it a huge difference is stretching it.

Comment: There's only one situation in which both could be considered to be all right, but otherwise, there's normally only one correct choice.

Answer (score 6):

My English teacher at school was adamant that *on to* was **always** two words, a position which is acknowledged by [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/onto):

> The preposition **onto** written as one word (instead of **on to**) is recorded from the early 18th century and has been widely used ever since, but is still not wholly accepted as part of standard British English (unlike **into,** for example). Many style guides still advise writing it as two words, and that is the practice followed in this dictionary. However, **onto** is more or less the standard form in US English and in the specialized mathematics sense. Nevertheless, it is important to maintain a distinction between the preposition **onto** or **on to** and the use of the adverb **on** followed by the preposition **to:** *she climbed **on to** (or **onto**) the roof* but *let’s go **on to** (not **onto**) the next point.*

In British English, it’s always safe to separate *on to;* in American English, *onto* would appear to be acceptable in almost all circumstances.

If *onto* can be one word in the examples given, one has to decide whether *on* can be classed as an adverb with *to* as the preposition, or whether *onto* is an acceptable preposition in its own right.

In Burchfield’s *New Fowler’s Modern English Usage* he quotes Fowler from 1926:

> Fowler (1926) added ... examples of *on* used as a full adverb before *to* and therefore written separately: *We must walk on to Keswick; Each passed it on to his neighbour; Struggling on to victory.* In *He played the ball on to his wicket,* he judged that “as *He played on* could stand by itself, it is hard to deny *on* its independent status”. It should also be noted that *They drove on to the beach* would normally mean “They continued their journey until they reached the beach” but could also mean ”They drove their vehicle to a position on the beach”; whereas *They drove onto the beach* could only mean ”They drove their vehicle to a position on the beach”.

With *hold on,* the *on* has Fowler’s “independent status”, and there is no sense of movement as there is with driving “onto a beach”. Indeed, the act of holding on to something is precisely to steady oneself and prevent movement! ***Hold on to*** is therefore appropriate.

In the second example [“grabbed onto the cushion”], with the verb *grab on* the *to* is needed (so *on* is not independent), and there may even be a sense of movement with a sudden taking-hold of the cushion. ***Grab onto*** might therefore be appropriate.

That said, customary forms in different dialects of English may dictate a different use. *Grab onto* looks decidedly wrong to my British eyes, conditioned as they are, even though I’ve argued fairly successfully from Fowler [a respected British authority] that it’s reasonable; and *hold on to* may look decidedly wrong to American eyes.

Comment: This one sure snuck up on me. I was sure it wasn’t right and was trying to edit it out of some text written by others. But apparently people push things “onto” stacks, or latch “onto” phrases, or release things “onto” a server for redistribution, or force a cast “onto” an argument.  It all still looks funny to me, but since it is apparently quite common, it’s funny that I think it funny. Odd.

Comment: @tchrist He's actually wrong. *On to* is correct for all of them.

Comment: No, we latch *on to* phrases.

Comment: Also, the word *on* is unnecessary in your sentence. *Release this to a server for redistribution.*

Comment: I do say that *on to* is always correct. But that doesn't mean that *onto* is necessarily incorrect. Arguments can be made for both points of view, even if I do not wholly agree with Fowler.

Comment: I've heard that's the standard in the UK, but *onto* in the US is strictly for moments of something being on top of something, whether it is virtually (I moved the icon onto the computer desktop) or literally (I jumped onto the floor). In the sentence *I latched on to/onto the phrase*, you aren't ending up on top of the phrase but rather using the verb *latch on*, meaning "to acquire."

Comment: While I'm at it, it's always *hold on to* and *grab on to*.

Comment: @SebastianPojman Since you have written your own answer, please refrain from arguing in comments on mine. I'm minded to suggest that these comments are removed.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I don't think I got my point across... Rather than fully disagreeing with you, I was only trying to add on to your comment.

Comment: The OED does recognise the existence of the combined form with plenty of examples e.g. 
*1715   Duxbury (Mass.) Rec. (1893) 105   [A] place gutted away by the rain down onto Mr. Wiswells land.

1830   R. Forby & G. Turner Ess. III, in R. Forby Vocab. E. Anglia I. 155   For the preposition upon, when it signifies motion to, we use onto (why not as good as into?). Ex. ‘Throw some coals onto the fire’.

2000   Ralph 7 July 86/3   His grip gave way and he dropped another 10 floors onto a cyclone fence.*

Answer (score 1):

The answer is *on to* in all of them because *grab on* and *hold on* are phrasal verbs. Also, there are general tricks that mostly work for the "onto/on to" sentences.

1. You can replace "onto" with upon.
2. It (sort of) works with only the "on."
3. You can add "up" or "down" before the "onto."

These tricks don't make sense with these examples, so that's another point for two words. In the end, here are the correct sentences.

*She held **on to** the cushion instead of holding **on to** the metal frame.
She was grabbing **on to** the seat cushion.
There's nothing saying what hand to use to hold **on to** any portion of the helicopter, and what part of the helicopter not to hold **on to** while getting in.*

DISCLAIMER: There really are no real sources for those tricks. They've been around for a long time, so just trust me.

Comment: How are my answers ALWAYS downvoted??

Comment: Because all the [people](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=held+on+to+the%2Cheld+onto+the+&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cheld%20on%20to%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cheld%20onto%20the%3B%2Cc0) who incorrectly use *hold onto* rather than *hold on to* feel offended by your calling their language ungrammatical?

Comment: In this case simply because it's factually incorrect. There is no such distinction as that which you mention, a fact supported by your own failure to produce any sources in corroboration.

Comment: Phrasal verbs have nothing to do with it: *move in* is a phrasal verb, and you say *I moved into my new house last week,* not *moved in to*.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: People spell this two different ways because they pronounce it two different ways. And trying to convince people to spell it *"hold on to"* when they pronounce it *"hold onto"* is a losing battle, so you might as well not even bother trying.

I think I've figured out what's going on here. Namely, I think I've figured out why writing *he held onto the rope* is so common, and why people are arguing about it so much.

Consider the examples:

> I drove on to the next town.
>   I drove onto the pier.

In these sentences, I pronounce *on to* slightly differently from *onto*: *onto* is a single word with the first syllable stressed, while in *on to*, the two words which have roughly equal stress.

However, in the sentence

> I held onto the bannisters,

I pronounce *onto* in the same way as in *I drove onto the pier,* despite the fact that *hold on* is a phrasal verb. However, some people pronounce this sentence as if *on* and *to* were different words. [Listen to Forvo.](https://forvo.com/phrase/hold_onto_the_banisters./)

I would guess that, in general, people are distinguishing between *on to* and *onto* by their pronunciations. You're not going to get people to change their pronunciation. And trying to get people to spell *hold on to* in a way they don't pronounce it is clearly a losing battle.

Which is correct? Clearly, for pronunciation, both alternatives should be considered correct. But in writing, I would suggest using *hold on to*. While normally, I'd suggest going by the pronunciation, that doesn't help here because it's pronounced both ways. And there are enough people who get upset at *hold onto* that you might as well make them happy. However, I also think it's pointless trying to get people who pronounce it *hold onto* to spell it *hold on to*. So, to avoid arguments, both spellings should be considered correct.

Comment: If anything, you only gave evidence proving why *on to* is right.

Comment: @SebastianPojman: The reasonable argument is that *I put the box onto the table* is pronounced the same as *I held on to the rope,* but differently from *he went on to become famous.* So if you believe that words are defined by their pronunciation, and not by their semantics, it should be *held onto*.

Comment: Nobody writes *went onto become*, because it's pronounced differently, but lots of people write *grab onto the*. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=went+onto+become%2C+went+on+to+become&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwent%20onto%20become%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwent%20on%20to%20become%3B%2Cc0) and [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=grabbed+on+to%2C+grabbed+onto&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgrabbed%20on%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgrabbed%20onto%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @Sebastian: I'm not trying to say *he held onto the rope* is correct. I'm trying to explain why lots of people write *he held onto the rope*, and nobody writes *he went onto become famous*.

Comment: The cat jumped onto the couch as the professor went on to his next point.....

Answer (score 0):

In the first and third sentences, use “on to” (two separate words)
because the verb is the idiom [hold on](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hold%20on),
meaning “to maintain a grasp on something” or simply “to grasp”. 
Fusing “on to” into “onto” would break the idiom
and leave you with the dictionary definition of “on”, which doesn’t fit your contexts. 
But I don’t see your second example as being right either way.

Comment: There's [absolutely nothing wrong](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/grab+on) with the second example. And it should be *on to* for the reason you give.

Comment: Ironic, then, that [the link you provided](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/grab+on) uses “grab onto” in an example.

Comment: *On to* is correct for all of them.

Comment: I, too, don't understand what could be wrong about the second example.